# mysqli_real_escape_string Clarification

Tags: php, mysqli, escaping

I started building a website a while ago and I kept hearing more and more about using `mysqli_real_escape_string`, however even though I know How to use it, I'm unsure of exactly when to use it. From what I can see I should only really need to use it when the user Inputs something into my website? At the moment I'm using a lot of jquery.post to send data between pages, some of which has been taken from the database already and some is from user inputs, so is it correct to escape everything that is passed or just what users add?

At the moment my code is:

```
$con = //Connection to Database

$time = time();
$id= time().'-'.mt_rand(1000, 9999);
$poster= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["poster"]);
$type= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["type"]);
$post= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["post"]);
$lat= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["lat"]);
$lon= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST["lon"]);
etc
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You should almost never use it. Use prepared statements and [bound parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) instead.

Whatever you use to protect your database from injection, you should apply it to all content that is not explicitly SQL already. This includes data that has been taken out of a database by another query (although you might want to look at using a JOIN to reduce your number of queries in that case).

Data that has come out of the database, been sent to the browser and then been sent back must be considered user input. It has been in the hands of users and can be modified by them.

(And don't allow users to pass data that is "explicitly SQL" to your server unless you are writing something which needs custom queries (like phpMyAdmin) and you trust the users **a lot**).

Answer (score -1):

> I'm unsure of exactly when to use it.

Two rules explains it

1. this function have to be applied for the **any** data that goes into SQL query as a **string literal**. Some consequences:

   - this function has absolutely nothing to do with whatever protections or injections
   - the data source being totally irrelevant. It's only destination - an SQL string literal - that matters
   - this function being totally useless for any other SQL literal
2. this function should never be used in the application code. The only place where it can be used - in the manual implementation of a parameterized query (if you have any). Otherwise it shouldn't be used at all, but prepared statements have to be used instead.

Speaking of prepared statements, mysqli implementation is quite hard to use. So, I would strongly recommend an abstraction library instead of raw mysqli functions - such as [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) or [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql)

Comment: Thanks, I'm just concerned with the number of connections I'm making to my database for everything that's passed. Is there a way to do it without connecting to the DB each time? $post_message = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $post_message); >> $post_message = mysqli_real_escape_string($post_message);

Comment: Why you are concerned with the number of connections? Why do you mean under "each time"? Why do you mean under "connecting"?

Comment: I've edited my original message to show what my code connections look like

Comment: your concern is groundless while your usage of this function is wrong.

Comment: No code was shown in any answer - I really have trouble understanding this as it's new to me. How do I edit the code I have to make it work?

Comment: Thanks. I understand that prepared statements are prefered but I'm not using PDO. I only want to use real_escape to limit what people are inputting but I've heard so much about sql injection that I'm trying to be careful. Will the real_escape method that I am using work to prevent injection in this case?

Comment: Nope, it wont work to prevent injection. That's what **everyone** talking about.

Comment: Ok, so to put it another way, what can I do to the code I have to **make** it injection proof? Other than using prepared statements?

Comment: Simple answer, I don't understand them well enough to use in this project

Comment: You don't understand mysqli_real_escape_string either